# Add a argument to a function in java

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-refactoring

I need to modify an argument to a function in Java. How do I add the argument to the callers using automation?

For example, In class A a method hello(int a ) exists. Now I am adding String to the same function argument so it becomes hello(String b , int a). If class B calls this method,how do I update the calling line in class B.

```
A a = new A();
int a; String b;
a.hello(a) % change to a.hello(b,a); //Assuming b is accessible.%
```

Eclipse provides this functionality via refactoring. Do they expose this API to external world or any other API is there?

Comment: not, you can't. You can adjust the code of A, or create a subclass of A and add that method in there

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click onto the method, select `Refactor` and select `Change Method Signature`. This opens a dialog that allows you to add new parameters, change parameter order, etc. When adding a new parameter you can provide a "Default Value" that will be used as argument in all classes that are currently calling the changed method.

Only classes with source that are currently in open Projects of the current Workspace are changed. The "outside world" will not get any notification of that. If you want to keep things runnable you should follow the advice to create a second method with the additional parameter and keep the old one (calling the new one with fitting default value). This can also automatically be done by mentioned refactor-dialog by checking the checkbox "keep original method as delegate to changed method".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find all calling instances of a method, I would overload the method to include a way to handle passing in a string.

```
Class A(int a){}

Class A(String a){}
```

when you call these methods with the appropriate argument, you call that specific method. If you already have method calls using String a as an argument, a)you should get compiler errors, but more importantly b)this would fix all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the method to add more parameters. All you have to do is define another method with the same name that takes different arguments.

```
public class A{
    public void hello(int a){
        //do things
    }
    public void hello(String b, int a){
        //do things
    }
}
```

The JVM will determine which method to use based on the given arguments during run time. If this isn't the functionality you need just give me a heads up.

Comment: I think you will find that i answered this exactly before you. >.<

Comment: @JasonV You are overloading the constructor not the method. They are different solutions, but similar.